# How to fix outdoor faucet drip when indoor shut off is off

Tags: plumbing, water

I just noticed that my outdoor faucet has a slow drip.  I checked the indoor shut off and it is closed tight.  What could be causing the problem and how would I fix it?  I don't know how long the drip has been happening -- I haven't used this particular faucet in years.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Replace the indoor shutoff, as it's obviously not closing all the way. Alternatively, if it's a gate valve, you could try repairing it. Though in my opinion, you might as well replace it. Replacing it with a ball valve, is usually a good choice.

You'll also want to replace the outdoor tap, as it's also not working. Again, you could possibly repair it, but it's probably just as easy to replace it. If you live in an area with freezing temperatures, you'll want to replace it with a frost-proof sillcock.